# Problema ao ler arquivo linha por linha em Java

Tags: java, netbeans

Olá, estou fazendo um programa em java para converter arquivos de csv para bib. Como o arquivo csv pode ter 200kb ou 2G decidi ler linha por linha para não ter problemas com falta de memória. Fiz o código da seguinte forma:

```
try {
  File file = new File(caminhoAbrirArquivos + nome);
  Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);

  linha = inputStream.nextLine();//A primeira linha é o cabeçalho, então descarto
  while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
    linha = inputStream.nextLine();

    //Código que realiza a conversão da linha
  }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: " + ex.getMessage(), "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Terminei o programa, testei e funcionou. Mas quando gerei o JAR para usar o programa ele leu apenas as primeiras 30 linhas do arquivo.

Quando executo o projeto no Netbeans ele lê todo o arquivo e converte, tudo certo, agora quando gero o JAR do projeto e executo ele lê apenas as primeiras 30 linhas do arquivo e converte apenas essas.

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: tenta executar o jar via linha de comando. Talvez está ocorrendo algum erro

Comment: Executei pela linha de comando, não apareceu nem um erro e leu apenas as primeiras 30 linhas.

Comment: E o arquivo por acaso não tem somente 30 linhas?

Comment: kkkkkk... não, tem 198 linhas.

Comment: Consegue disponibilizar o arquivo?

Comment: Cheira a uma linha vazia no arquivo ou tag de EOF

Comment: Coloquei o arquivo no Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7yryzIu_P8XS1I2T05XMXd6clE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver utilizando os objetos *FileReader* e *BufferedReader*, o código ficou assim:

```
FileReader arq = new FileReader(caminhoAbrirArquivos + nome);
BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);

linha = lerArq.readLine();//Primeira linha é o cabeçalho, então é descartada
linha = lerArq.readLine();

while (linha != null) {
    //Código que faz a conversão
}
```